# How to update data immediately in table after submitting using php?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html

I have successfully inserted my data into database table, now I want to show it in front view i.e., in my html table as well, as soon as I made an entry my table also gets updated immediately!

here is the html I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js">        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="font:17px Consolas;" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 offset1 main-entry" ng-controller="priceController">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Add new entry</legend>

                  <label>Tea Total:</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="teaPrice" id="book-name"><br><br>

                  <label>Snacks Total:</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="snacksPrice" id="book-price"><br><br>

                  <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" ng-click="insertdata()">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="table-show">
        <table style="border: 2px solid #111">
            <tr>
                <th>Tea Total</th>
                <th>Snacks Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hii</td>
                <td>hi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td>hi</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my main.js file which also includes angular js, as I have angularjs to fetch values :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('priceController', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.insertdata = function() {
                $http.post('insert.php',{'teaPrice' : $scope.teaPrice, 'snacksPrice' : $scope.snacksPrice})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("data inserted successfully");
                });
            }
        });
```

And at last is my insert.php which is inserting values in the database:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trial");

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo $data ->teaPrice;
    echo $data ->snacksPrice;
    $teaPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data ->teaPrice);
    $snacksPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data ->snacksPrice);
    $details = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `try` (`teaPrice`, `snacksPrice`) VALUES ('".$teaPrice."', '".$snacksPrice."')");
    $a = 0;
    if($details > 0){
        $a = 1;

    }

?>
```

Comment: Inside your success function call back your get data method - `success(function(data, status, headers, config){ getdata() }`

Comment: I think there is need to write some code of php in the table's td as well!

Comment: If you want to get the new values added to your table, you can do that with javascript inside the `success:` function. Let your PHP script return e.g. a JSON encoded array with something like `['status' => true]` to indicate whether everything is ok, then add the values (They still are avaiable from the variables you passed to the AJAX request). Just created a new row for your table and append it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to loop the data and bind it on the td's using ng-repeat.
Lets say you are getting response into  `$scope.priceDetails = data` inside your getData() method which will be a get call.

Then you can do like this -

```
   <table style="border: 2px solid #111">
        <tr>
            <th>Tea Total</th>
            <th>Snacks Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "item in priceDetails">
            <td>{{item.teaTotal}}</td>
            <td>{{item.snacksTotal}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

The above naming properties are as per my assumption.You can create your own response and just use ng-repeat to bind the details on table.